# Accessing .net core website hosted on Ubuntu 16.04 through internet

Tags: linux, .net-core, cross-platform, ubuntu-16.04, asp.net-core-2.0

I am following along [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z5dnNthXwzE&t=2539s) to deploy my asp.net application onto Ubuntu.  I have installed .Net core 2.0 on my Ubuntu machine using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/linux-prerequisites?tabs=netcore2x) post.  NO issues with that excellent article.

My VM configuration is :

```
 user@instance-2:~/dev/mywebsite$ lsb_release -a
    No LSB modules are available.
    Distributor ID: Ubuntu
    Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
    Release:        16.04
    Codename:       xenial
```

I have confirm that .Net core is installed properly.

```
user@instance-2:~/dev/mywebsite$ dotnet --info
.NET Command Line Tools (2.0.0)
Product Information:
 Version:            2.0.0
 Commit SHA-1 hash:  cdcd1928c9
Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     ubuntu
 OS Version:  16.04
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         ubuntu.16.04-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.0.0/
Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host
  Version  : 2.0.0
  Build    : e8b8861ac7faf042c87a5c2f9f2d04c98b69f28d
```

Next I have created new dot net web application using below command

```
dotnet new web
```

set ASPNETCORE_URLS environment variable

```
export ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5123
```

Confirmed that its set properly.

```
user@instance-2:~/dev/mywebsite$ echo $ASPNETCORE_URLS
http://+:5123
```

Ran my application using dotnet run.  Can see below message on console.

```
user@instance-2:~/dev/mywebsite$ dotnet run
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: /home/hemant_shelar/dev/mywebsite
Now listening on: http://[::]:5123
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

Expected: I should be able to browse this site from internet using IP address
like : http://35.185.21.120:5123/  But I am not able to access this site from outside.  Getting `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` error.

Note: 35.185.21.120 is IP address of my Ubuntu machine which is in google cloud.

Am I missing any configuration?

**UPDATE 1:** 
I have open port 5123 using below command

```
sudo ufw enable

sudo ufw allow 5123
```

Verified that port is opened using below command:

```
hemant_shelar@instance-2:~/dev/mywebsite$ sudo ufw status
Status: active
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
5123                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
5123 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

But still same issue.

**UPDATE 2**
I set environment variable ASPNETCORE_URLS to http://+:80

```
hemant_shelar@instance-2:~/dev/mywebsite$ echo $ASPNETCORE_URLS
http://+:80
hemant_shelar@instance-2:~/dev/mywebsite$ sudo dotnet run
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: /home/hemant_shelar/dev/mywebsite
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

But when I run website its listing on port 5000.  Is there any other way to expose site on port 80?  e.g. in IIS we use http host header to open multiple sites on port 80.

Comment: First of all, you don't want to expose Kestrel directly without a reverse proxy. Second, your host firewall might restrict port 5123. Make sure 35.185.21.120:5123 is configured to be accessible for inbound or try port 80 instead.

Comment: @IvanZaruba Thanks for your input.  I have open port 5123 using 'sudo ufw allow 5223' command.  and 'sudo ufw status' shows that port is open.  Still same issue.  Can you please throw some light on 'don't want to expose Kestrel directly without a reverse proxy'?  I am new to the linux world and its not as simple as hosting site in IIS.  Appreciate any pointer to solve this.

Comment: You have 5123 opened but your host might have blocked the inbound to that. Take a shot with port 80, it is typically the one to be used for http access. As to a reverse proxy, Kestrel is not considered to be a full web server, so we need some stuff like nginx that is a reverse proxy. Basically nginx accepts the request and proxies it to Kestrel via http.

Comment: @IvanZaruba I set environment variable ASPNETCORE_URLS to http://+:80 but when I am running website it runs on port 5000.  See my UPDATE 2

Comment: Here's what I have root@ubuntu:~/test# export ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80
root@ubuntu:~/test# echo $ASPNETCORE_URLS
http://+:80
root@ubuntu:~/test# dotnet run
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: /home/dev/test
Now listening on: http://[::]:80
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down. So basically this is something to do with your OS policy, not the .NET Core

Comment: Thanks @IvanZaruba, I think issue was I didn't had access to root.  After running 'sudo -s' and opening port 80 I was able to access site at http://35.185.21.120/